# How to find all extensions of file in directory

Tags: python-3.x, file, directory

I am trying to list all extensions of file e.g. file.txt, file.png, file.xml, file.pdf.
I know that file is in directory but I know what kind of extensions it might have.

Also files might have custom extension for instance file.source_1 thus creating list and checking might be very inefficient.

Result should be a list/tuple (txt, png, xml, pdf, ...)

Comment: i am not sure if i understand you correctly but maybe something like this? `print([os.path.splitext(file)[1] for file in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isfile(file)])`

Answer (score 0):

### This is operating system specific.

For Linux, you want to use [opendir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) with [readdir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html). Both are wrapped in Python in its [filesys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filesys.html) and [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os) module.

> Also files might have custom extension for instance file.source_1 thus creating list and checking might be very inefficient.

On computers with real rotating hard disks, the bottleneck would be the disk access time.

At last, some other [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (outside of your Python script) might change your file system (while your Python script is running).

For huge directories or file systems (e.g. terabytes) consider caching and memoizing that information (e.g. in some [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) database)

Comment: I think it will be something like ten different extensions in each folder but for sure they might vary among each other. 
Unfortunately it is windows.